# Ops unit in Grafana

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, micrometer

I have put annotation io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed on a spring rest endpoint and configured prometheus. It provides me with three metrics on grafana:

```
myMetricsName_seconds_count
myMetricsName_seconds_sum
myMetricsName_seconds_max
```

Going by the name, I assume count tells total number of times endpoint is called, sum gives us total time these all calls take, and max tells the maximum time taken amongst all these calls.

On Grafana, the graph I see for these 3 metrics have same unit for Y axis - ops.

Shouldn't units be different?

Comment: Do you mean they have the same value?
It would be helpful if you could send the values or a screenshot of what you see in grafana. What values do you see on the prometheus endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `count` is the total calls and `sum` is the total duration. `max` is the max in a moving window, (as in 'max in the last minute')

The units should be different in Grafana. However, if you are asking if the `count` should be named something different than `myMetricsName_seconds_count`, the reason it has 'seconds' in the name is to keep it parallel to its matching sum.

That way you can infer they are correlated and can divide the sum by the count to get the average duration.